# Cycle slideshow: only autoshow some specified slides

Tags: jquery, slideshow, cycle

I'm using the Cycle plugin for my slideshow: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

The slides starts automatic and uses a navigation that gets fired with an hover.

I would like that the slideshow only slides through specified slides, and only shows the other ones when they are hovered in the navigation.

I hope someone understands.

Edit:
I've made an image. Maybe that makes a bit more clear what I try to achieve. 
http://www.vrds.nl/foto/slide_example.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, there is a version 2 of the cycle plugin located here (https://github.com/malsup/cycle2)

API: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/api/

In order to do this, you just need to hook into the cycle-after event and when the slide is on the 3rd one to pause the slideshow.

```
$( '#mySlideshow' ).on( 'cycle-after', function( event, opts ) {
   if (opts.currSlide==2) $('#mySlideshow').cycle('pause');  // pause on 3rd one
});
```

For the hover overs, you can just attach an event to them.  Assuming the right part are `li` elements (they can be whatever just making an assumption here):

```
$('li').mouseover(function() {
   $('#mySlideshow').cycle('goto', $(this).index());  // something like this;
});
```

If you don't want to use the second most up to date version of the plugin, the logic is exactly the same.